# Mock patch with __init__.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

My code is organized as follows:

dir/A.py:

```
from X import Y

class A:
    ...
```

dir/__init__.py:

```
from .A import A
__all__ = ['A']
```

tests/test_A.py:

```
class test_A:
    @patch("dir.A.Y")
    def test(self, mock_Y):
        ....
```

On running tests/test_A.py, I (as expected) get the error:

```
AttributeError: <class 'dir.A.A'> does not have the attribute 'Y'
```

The issue is that `@patch("dir.A.y")` tries to find `Y` in class `dir.A.A`, rather than in the module `dir.A` (where it is actually present).

This is clearly because of my `__init__.py`. I could overcome this by changing the module-name `A` and the class-name `A` to different symbols.

The way the code is organized, I want to avoid such a naming change. How can I use `patch` in a way that it finds `Y` in the correct place?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `patch.object()` decorator instead, and retrieve the module from `sys.modules`:

```
@patch.object(sys.modules['dir.A'], 'Y')
def test(self, mock_Y):
    ...
```

Comment: Basically what I said, but earlier. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: There is basically exactly one answer to this question. :)